# Поле класса, как умный указатель?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

В С++ при объявлении в классе указателя (поле класса), как правильно его прописывать? Просто как указатель? Или как умный указатель?

Вот например класс А:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QMultiMap>
#include <QSharedPointer>


class A
{
    struct Node{
         QSharedPointer<Node> shLink_1;
         QSharedPointer<Node> shLink_2;
         QSharedPointer<Node> shLink_3;
         QSharedPointer<Node> shLink_4;
         QSharedPointer<Node> shParent;
         QVector<int> nodeState;
         int nodeCost;
         int distance;
         int indexEmpty;

         Node() : shLink_1(nullptr), shLink_2(nullptr), shLink_3(nullptr),
           shLink_4(nullptr), shParent(nullptr){}
};

     QSharedPointer<Node> m_shRoot;
     QMultiMap<int, QSharedPointer<Node>> m_MultiMapOpen;
     QList<QSharedPointer<Node>> m_ListClose;
     QList<QVector<int>> m_ListResult;

public:
     explicit A();
     bool solvePuzzle();
     QList<QVector<int>> getSolution(int &moves);

private:
     bool checkNewNode(const QSharedPointer<Node> &shCurNode);
};
```

Адекватно так описывать класс?

Comment: Ну и код бы не помешало сократить демонстрационный. Если ещё не читали, почитайте что такое [mcve].

Comment: Вижу, что в вашем коде есть циклические ссылки умных указателей

Comment: @Unick а конкретней: где? почему? как исправить?

Comment: Судя по этому:         QSharedPointer<Node> shLink_4;         QSharedPointer<Node> shParent; нод ссылается на парента, а паррент ссылается на нод. Следовательно нод и парент не дадут удалить друг-друга, т.к. на каждого будет как минимум одна ссылка.